# Xubuntu 18.04 sometimes freezes when turned on on logo

Tags: xubuntu

Sometimes when I turn off the computer, it hangs on the logo. What is the problem? Prior to this, the computer did not want to boot with the 4.15 kernel. When I updated the BIOS, the computer started to boot. Maybe the problem is in the bios again?

Here is a hang https://ibb.co/PcYvDLq

Mysystem unit - HP-Compaq-dc5800-Microtower

Comment: Try updating the kernel to latest version. [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2868) is an indication that this could be a kernel issue.

Comment: At the moment I have a kernel 5.0.0-25